# Plotting Point and Line plot in XYPLOT Lattice

Tags: r, plot, lattice

I need a guidance related to plotting. with lattice package.I am trying to plot `xyplot(median + Temp + Rule1 + Rule3 ~ time | factor(name),data=v1,pch=19,grid=19,grid=TRUE,main="Time Series Analysis",xlab="Time",layout=c(1,1),points=TRUE,size=50,fill="transparent"))`
here Rule1,Rule2,Rule3 are categorical variable whereas median and temp are numerical my query is how can we show categorical plot as point plot and numerical variable as line plot in XYplot formatlattice
[image: Temp and Median is (numerical Variable -Expecting plot is Line) **Rule1 Rule2 Rule3** are *categorical variable* -*Expected Plot is Point* and further it is factored in name and layout in (1,1)] Hence Expected Plot is also specified Pardon me for made up visualisation [image]

Comment: **Point to be Noted : ** the categorical Rule1 has two level (0,45) Rule2 has two level (0,48) & Rule3 has two level (0,50).Such that these are event based on the time series as an x-axis.

Comment: So , Finally what required is The variable `temp` and `median` - **Line Plot** & `Rule1` `Rule2` & `Rule3` Would be **Point Plot** as shown in Expected Figure

Comment: Please try to clean up your example and provide a minimal working example. [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). At least try to use `dput` or simulate some data that we can use to help you.